# How long do unpaid bills remain visible on credit report?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, default

If one has an unpaid bill from a non-credit institution, such as a gym or a doctor's office, how long does that stay visible on the credit report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seven years.   From the [Equifax FAQ](http://blog.equifax.com/credit/faq-how-long-does-information-stay-on-my-credit-report/):

> In general, negative information more than seven years old from the date of last activity (ten years for bankruptcies) must be removed from your file.